How can I overlay multiple views in SwiftUI so that they appear above the main content view
(for visionOS)
What I want to do is position the pop-up windows so that they appear above the main ContentView, while ensuring that the ContentView remains visible.
They don't pop up at once, so i want to do for example is place them all above the main ContentView. How can i do it?
I have already enabled Multiple Windows. Let me be clear what I want to move is the WindowGroup.
@main
struct Demo17App: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase

    var body: some Scene {
        let viewModel = OptionsViewModel()

        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(viewModel: viewModel)
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
                
        }
        .windowStyle(.plain)

        WindowGroup(id: "firstWindow") {
            Text("Second Window Content [Information]")
                .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .zIndex(100)
        }
        .handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "firstWindow"))
        .windowStyle(.plain)

        WindowGroup(id: "secondWindow") {
            VideoView()
                .zIndex(100)
            
        }
        .handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "secondWindow"))

        WindowGroup(id: "thirdWindow") {
            ImmersiveView()
                .zIndex(100)
        }
        .handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "thirdWindow"))
    }
}


Did you enable Multiple Windows? As far as I can tell you need to open each WindowGroup separately. Also have a look at WWDC video about multi window support

yes i did enable Multiple Windows,but the problem is When I launch new window the system places the new one in front of the one of the app’s existing window, and what i want to do is trying to control the position of the this new window

Alright, please add that information to your description.

You can't control where a new window appears in visionOS. The OS will place it front and center for the user. If you really want to control the location of all windows for your app, you'll have to use one single WindowGroup, with a transparent background, and place all of your content windows on that hosting superwindow. I don't think that's a good idea, because you're fighting the system framework and you're fighting user expectations on how the platform works. But if you really want to do that, that's a way forward.

okay, thanks, i was thinking of using multiple Spacer() , it did work but still i can't keep the main view always displayed

you can also use immersive view, by creating a attachment that shows your swiftUI content, then attach it to certain point in space, for example, if you want it to be above the main content, then try setting the attachment to be
let attachmentId = "attachmentId"
RealityView { content, attachments in

            if let attachment = attachments.entity(for: attachmentId){
               attachment.position = [0,1.8,-1.3] //center, 1.8 meter above ground, 1.3 meter to the front of you 
               content.add(attachment)
            }
} attachments: {
Attachment(id: attachmentId) {
                YourView()
                    .frame(width: XXX, height: XXX)
}

